# Import AppleScript methods in another AppleScript?

Tags: import, applescript

Is there a way to use defined AppleScript methods in other AppleScripts which reference the original AppleScript with something similar to import (f.e. in PHP)?

I wrote a methode to set Skype status and mood-text:

```
on setSkypeStatus(status, mood_text)
    tell application "System Events"
        set skypeRunning to count (every process whose name is "Skype")

        if skypeRunning > 0 then --only set status if skype is running
            tell application "Skype"
                set myStatus to "SET USERSTATUS " & status
                set myMood to "SET PROFILE MOOD_TEXT " & mood_text

                send command myStatus script name "AppleScript"
                send command myMood script name "AppleScript"
                return skypeRunning
            end tell
        else
            return skypeRunning
        end if
    end tell
end setSkypeStatus
```

now I'm searching for something like **import skype_methods.scpt**. Is there such a functionality. I can't something related with Google.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One way to import another script as a library is to define a property which is initialized by loading the library as a script object. You can then use the `tell` command to invoke the library functions.

```
property pSkypeLibrary : load script POSIX file "/Users/sakra/Desktop/skype_methods.scpt"

tell pSkypeLibrary
    setSkypeStatus("status", "mood")
end tell
```

Comment: I tried to find this info in apple documentation but was not able to do this. Do you know where I can find it?

Answer (score 3):

*Script `Foo.scpt`*

```
set theBar to "path:to:Bar.scpt" as alias
run script (theBar)
```

*Script `Bar.scpt`*

```
display dialog "Bar"
```

*Result:* A window that displays "Bar"

Answer (score 3):

There is a more elegant way of doing this. You can save your skype_methods.scpt file inside a Script Libraries folder on your computer.

Depending on how you want to define the availability of this library, you use a different folder.

- Place the skype_methods.scpt file inside the `/Library/Script Libraries` folder to make it available for all users on the computer.
- Place it in the `~/Library/Script Libraries` folder to make it available for a specific user only.

You can then use all the handlers in that library as follows:

```
property Skype : script "skype_methods"
Skype's setSkypeStatus("status","mood")
```

This prevents the need of numerous tell blocks when using handlers from different libraries.

Answer (score -1):

You can follow this repo https://github.com/abbeycode/AppleScripts which organises its scripts into libraries

Here is an example https://github.com/abbeycode/AppleScripts/blob/master/Scripts/Download%20Chase%20Activity.applescript

```
property LibLoader : load script file ((path to scripts folder from user domain as text) & "Libraries:Library Loader.scpt")
property TransmissionLib : LibLoader's loadScript("Libraries:Transmission.applescript")
property GrowlLib : LibLoader's loadScript("Libraries:Growl.applescript")
property SafariLib : LibLoader's loadScript("Libraries:Safari.applescript")
property DatesLib : LibLoader's loadScript("Libraries:Dates.applescript")
```