# #include like directive in AppleScript

Tags: include, applescript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Import AppleScript methods in another AppleScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606136/import-applescript-methods-in-another-applescript)

Is there anything in AppleScript that can be used like the `#include` directive in C?

For instance:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTIVE "Path/To/Applescript.scpt"

//Some AppleScript code here
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606136/import-applescript-methods-in-another-applescript.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Absolutely you can do this, and there are two variations. The first loads the entire script:

*Script Foo.scpt*

```
set theBar to "path:to:Bar.scpt" as alias
run script (theBar)
```

*Script Bar.scpt*

```
display dialog "Bar"
--Result: A window that displays "Bar"
```

The second allows you load a script and call specific methods within that script:

*Foo.scpt*

```
property OopLib : load script POSIX file "/Users/philipr/Desktop/OopLib.app"
tell OopLib
    set theResult to Oop(1)
    display dialog theResult
end tell
--> result: Window displaying "Eek: 1"
```

*OopLib.scpt*

```
on Oop(Eek)
    display dialog Eek
    return "Eek: " & Eek
end Oop
```

Answer (score 3):

Use something like this to load the script

```
set scriptLibraryPath to (path to scripts folder from user domain as text) & "myScript.scpt"
set scriptLibrary to load script scriptLibraryPath as alias
```

Then to access a subroutine in that script do this...

```
set myValue to someMethod() of scriptLibrary
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to what other posters have said, `load script` is the only built-in option; it's very primitive, but may be sufficient if your needs are modest.

Late Night Software's [Script Debugger](http://www.latenightsw.com) editor provides an #include-style library mechanism that can merge multiple AppleScript files when compiling a script. The downside of Script Debugger is that it's a couple hundred bucks to buy, though many regular AppleScript users will tell you it's well worth the investment.

There are a couple of third-party module loaders, [Loader](http://applemods.sourceforge.net) and [ModuleLoader](http://homepage.mac.com/tkurita/scriptfactory/en/XModules), that implement more sophisticated import mechanisms on top of the basic `load script` command, and are worth looking into if your requirements are more complex. I've not used ModuleLoader, but Loader (which I wrote) can import modules at compile- or run-time from various standard and user-specified locations, and will automatically resolve complex (even circular) dependencies between modules.

The downsides of Loader and ModuleLoader is that they rely on scripting additions to do some of the heavy lifting, which might be an issue when distributing scripts (in Loader's case, the osax is only needed to compile scripts, not to run them), plus you need to add some boilerplate code to your script to perform the actual import.