# How do you do an include in applescript?

Tags: applescript

I have a bunch of code I want to to use in several different applescripts so I would like to put it into it's own applescript that I can reference from other applescripts.  Basically I want to do an include.  How is this done in applescript?

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606136/import-applescript-methods-in-another-applescript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the best way I have found to accomplish this. You can call a function on another script like so:

script `a.scpt`

```
set myScript to load script "b.scpt"
set foo to myScript's theTest()
```

script `b.scpt`

```
on theTest()
       return true
end theTest
```

As you can see you can call functions within b.scpt from a.scpt by calling the function name myScript's theTest().

Comment: Very close but you got me on the right track.  I tried this with both files on my desktop and it says it can't make b.scpt into type file.  I think I found the solution.  This makes it work.                                                           tell application "Finder"
 set thePath to POSIX path of ((container of (path to me)) as text)
end tell
set myScript to load script thePath

set foo to myScript's theTest()

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the handlers and scripts that you want to reference inside a Script Library (for example: `my_math_lib.scpt` and `my_string_lib.scpt`). Then, save this file in a Script Libraries folder on your computer.

Depending on how you want to define the availability of this library, you use a different folder:

- Place the `my_math_lib.scpt` and `my_string_lib.scpt` files inside the `/Library/Script Libraries` folder to make them available for all users on the computer.
- Place them in the `~/Library/Script Libraries` folder to make them available for a specific user only.

You can then use all the handlers in those libraries as follows:

```
property math_lib : script "my_math_lib"
property string_lib : script "my_string_lib"
math_lib's do_this()
string_lib's do_that()
```