# What does error –1752 "Script doesn’t seem to belong to AppleScript." actually mean?

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm trying to write several AppleScript scripts that share common functions.  Ideally, they would [include a separate file where these functions are defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4311090/2063546).

Since this will be in a repository instead of locked to a particular machine, I can't rely on the script library directory to do it.  I'm trying to [load a script from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152552/relative-file-paths-with-applescript).

But none of it seems to work.  At first, I thought the problem was related to [spaces in the directory name](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/617367), but after doing a test where I include from a directory that does not contain spaces, it's clear that `osascript` is finding the file and just refusing to open it.

> error "Script doesn’t seem to belong to AppleScript." number -1752 from "/path/to/common.applescript"

What does this even mean, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Is your AppleScript stored in text format as opposed to compiled script format?

Comment: It's in text format, since it's part of a repository.

Comment: @Zero that doesn't help me much.  Googling that error gives me [information that seems completely unrelated](http://www.macerrorsolution.com/-1752%20errOSABadStorageType.php).

Answer (score 6):

AppleScript's built-in library loader (10.9+) and `load script` command (all OS versions) require compiled (`.scpt`/`.scptd`) AppleScript files [1]. OSA knows nothing about source code file formats (e.g. `.applescript`) and does not have the ability to read or write them itself; only external tools like Script Editor, `osacompile`, `osadecompile` know how to do that.

You can either store the compiled files in your repo [2], or you can write a deployment script that runs the uncompiled (`.applescript`) files through `osacompile` when copying them to your `Script Libraries` folder (or wherever it is you're deploying them).

--

[1] 
Yes, it's annoying, but OSA predates "modern" SCM systems and its file system interaction was modeled more on [Smalltalk machine](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ImageBasedLanguage) style persistence, rather than Unix's "let's pretend everything is an ASCII text file" approach.

[2]
Though you'll lose the ability to diff them, unless you want to muck about with your SCM's diff hooks so it runs `.scpt[d]` files through `osadecompile` to create temporary `.applescript` files that can then be diffed as normal.

Comment: I have posted a diffscript at [MacScripter / Show differences in two AppleScript files with TextWrangler](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=33758) (#post 24) This works with scpt and probably scptd files, as long as it is the main script of a scptd file we are talking about. (Doesn't use scptd that much).