# Import global variable in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

How can I import a global variable from one AppleScript file into another?

I am using two AppleScript files to create a demo for a project course.

One AppleScript file "main.scpt" begins with a global variable

```
global someDirectory
set someDirectory to "~/Documents/cs123-drj/demo"

on openServerWindow()
    # Open the server
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "n" using command down
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "i" using {command down, shift down}
    typeKeys("server")
    typeKeys(return)
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "i" using command down
    typeKeys("cd ")
    typeKeys(someDirectory)
    typeKeys(return)
    typeKeys("./cs123-server.sh")
    typeKeys(return)
end openServerWindow
```

This works fine when executed from this file. I would like to use this file as a library, in a similar to fashion to what is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606136/import-applescript-methods-in-another-applescript). The full text of my second AppleScript follows.

```
#
# Demo script for doing simultaneous selects from a CS123-DRJ database.
#

property CS123Commands : load script POSIX file "/Users/admin/Documents/cs123-drj/demo/main.scpt"

tell CS123Commands to openServerWindow()
```

When I attempt to run this code, I get the following error:

> error "The variable someDirectory is not defined." number -2753 from
>   "someDirectory"

How can I import this variable into my second AppleScript file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not actually running the script when you load it so someDirectory never gets set. You can fix this by making it a property instead. So change this...

```
global someDirectory
set someDirectory to "~/Documents/cs123-drj/demo"
```

to...

```
property someDirectory: "~/Documents/cs123-drj/demo"
```