# Loading an applescript library dynamicly

Tags: applescript, shared-libraries

Is there a way to load an applescript library based on a variable.
What I try to achieve is this:

```
set basescript to "hello.scpt"

tell script basescript
    dialoger("testing")
end tell
```

the basescript will contain something like:

```
on dialoger(message)
    display dialog message
end dialoger
```

This works fine a long as I type it out but as soon I try to pass it like a var it keeps giving errors...
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import AppleScript methods in another AppleScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606136/import-applescript-methods-in-another-applescript)

Comment: No unfortunately not. These methods all work fine but none of them seem to be working when this script name is being presented in the form of a variable as show above.

Comment: If you do `set basescript to load script POSIX file "/path/to/Hello.scpt"` then `tell basescript to dialoger("testing")` will work!

Comment: Your solution works as suggested!
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I use script libraries all the time. Once you get the hang of it, it becomes a huge timesaver.  There are a couple of ways of loading script commands from a “Library Script” into another script.

One way is to use the `load script` command by setting a variable name to `load script` and `path/to/script`.

There is also another way, which in my opinion, is much more powerful.  You can import library scripts using the `use` statement.  This method removes the need of using `tell statements`.

For example, I saved your following code as “Hello.scpt” in my /Users/YOUR SHORT NAME/Library/Script Libraries/ folder.

```
on dialoger(message)
    display dialog message
end dialoger
```

Next, in the script in which I want to load the commands from the Library script “Hello.scpt”, this is the code I used using the `use statement`

```
use basescript : script "Hello"
use scripting additions

basescript's dialoger("testing")
```

[By using use statements with multiple applications, you can combine terms from different sources in ways impossible using standard tell statements or tell blocks, because the tell construct only makes one terminology source available at a time.](https://macosxautomation.com/mavericks/usestatement/02.html)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

If you do set basescript to load script POSIX file "/path/to/Hello.scpt" then tell basescript to dialoger("testing") will work!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that these are script libraries, you can accomplish what you want using a handler like so:

```
-- send the same of the script library in the first parameter
-- and the message in the second

myHandler("hello", "My Message")

on myHandler(libName, message)
    tell script libName
        dialoger(message)
    end tell
end test
```

Since the handler isn't processed until runtime, it will dynamically implement the correct script library passed in libName.